# JFrame shows Content only when u drag the frame bigger?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I got very simple code it shows a very simple calculator GUI without function, but unfortunately the content only appears when I drag the window bigger. I think it's a problem whit the code structure, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Maybe it is a bug from my computer or problem with my IDE, I'm using IntelliJ. I searched a lot in web, but the problem is kinda hard to find.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calculator {

    public void showGUI(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Calculator");
        Container cont = window.getContentPane();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(300,300);
        window.setVisible(true);

        JTextField textfieldfirstinput = new JTextField("                ");
        JTextField textfieldsecondinput = new JTextField("                ");
        JTextField textfieldsolutionoutput = new JTextField("                ");

        JButton buttonadden = new JButton("+");
        JButton buttonmultiply = new JButton("*");
        JButton buttonclear = new JButton("Clear");
        JButton buttonexit = new JButton("Exit");

        JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel textfieldpanel = new JPanel();

        textfieldpanel.add(textfieldfirstinput,textfieldsecondinput);
        textfieldpanel.add(textfieldsolutionoutput);
        //textfieldpanel.setLayout();
        textfieldpanel.setVisible(true);

        buttonpanel.add(buttonadden);
        buttonpanel.add(buttonmultiply);
        buttonpanel.add(buttonclear);
        buttonpanel.add(buttonexit);
        //buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonpanel.setVisible(true);

        cont.add(buttonpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cont.add(textfieldpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cont.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
        window.add(cont);


    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.showGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main issues in your code:

1. `window.setVisible(true);` should be called last in your code, after you've added everything to it. That will solve the issue of the resizing.
2. You also get an error when running it:

   ```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
    at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.sof.frakcool.Calculator.showGUI(Calculator.java:47)
    at com.sof.frakcool.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:56)
   ```

   This means that you're adding a component to itself.

   When you call `Container cont = window.getContentPane();`, you're not removing that component from its parent, just creating a reference to it, so there's no need for this line

   ```
    window.add(cont);
   ```

   And then you'll have your program running just fine.

Also there's no need to call:

```
textfieldpanel.setVisible(true);
buttonpanel.setVisible(true);
```

And as an additional tip, you can replace this:

```
JTextField textfieldfirstinput = new JTextField("                ");
```

With

```
JTextField textfieldfirstinput = new JTextField(10);
```

Which will set the number of columns it will expand, you won't have to remove all the spaces when you write into it.

And please follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) using camel-case to name your properties, and give them meaningful names, such as `firstNumberInput` rather than `textfieldfirstinput`

- `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
- `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
- `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`
- `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASED_CONSTANT`

Comment: Ah yeah .. fixed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: If that fixed it please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer